# Airflow MySQL connection parameters with URI

Tags: mysql, uri, airflow

I'm trying to use the MySqlHook.bulk_load() method [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/code.html#airflow.hooks.MySqlHook.get_conn) in my Airflow task, and if my understanding is correct, I have to enable "local_infile" and "loose-local-infile" when I create the connection to my MySQL database in order for this to work.

Otherwise, it results in the following error: 
"The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version."

If I create my connection from the Connections page on the webserver UI, and pass the following parameters as "extras", the method is successful and the DAG works as intended: 
{"local_infile":"1","loose-local-infile":"1"}
[image of connection settings on Airflow webserver UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCXvM.png)

However, I am looking create my database connection by passing it as an environmental variable instead. To do so, requires me to pass my connection settings as a URI. [see "Connections" in docs](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html)

ie: `scheme://[user[:[password]]@]target[:port][/schema][?attribute1=value1&attribute2=value2...`
[docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-shell-connection-using-uri.html)

I have tried the following formats, but none have worked successfully for me:

`mysql://user:password@hostname:port/schema?local_infile=1&loose-local-infile=1`
`mysql://user:password@hostname:port/schema?local_infile=1;loose-local-infile=1`

I have also tried percent encoding my values like so:
`mysql://user:password@hostname:port/schema?local_infile%3D1%26loose-local-infile%3D1`

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated, thank you!